# C# - Exception handling from within finally clause

Tags: c#, exception

The title is a bit misleading but the issue seems very straight-forward to me. I have `try-catch-finally` block. I want to execute the code in the `finally` block only if an exception was thrown from the `try` block. The structure of the code right now is:

```
try
{
  //Do some stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Handle the exception
}
finally
{
  //execute the code only if exception was thrown.
}
```

Right now the only solution I can think of is setting a flag like:

```
try
{
  bool IsExceptionThrown = false;
  //Do some stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  IsExceptionThrown = true;
  //Handle the exception   
}
finally
{
if (IsExceptionThrown == true)
  {
  //execute the code only if exception was thrown.
  }
}
```

Not that I see something bad in this but wonder if there is another(better) approach to check if there's a thrown exception?

Comment: Why would not you put the code in the catch() section ?

Comment: What you're looking for is `fault`, which exists in the CLR, but has never been implemented in C#.

Comment: @Laurent - I'd imagine an actual usage would be if there are multiple `catch` clauses and then some common code that should be executed if any exception occurred would be a more substantial example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Agreed. If only if could work as a Switch/Case...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about something like:

```
try
{
    // Do some stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle the exception
    // Execute the code only if exception was thrown.
}
finally
{
    // This code will always be executed
}
```

That's what `Catch` block are made for!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `finally` for this. It is intended for code that should *always* execute.

What exactly is the difference, in terms of when to execute, between

```
//Handle the exception
```

and

```
//execute the code only if exception was thrown.
```

I can't see any.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `finally` after all:

```
try
{
  //Do some stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Handle the exception
  //execute the code only if exception was thrown.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Finally part of a Try / Catch statement is always fired regardless of whether any exceptions have been found. I would recommend you don't use it in this scenario.

```
try
{
  // Perform Task
}
catch (Exception x)
{
  //Handle the exception error.

}
Finally
{
  // Will Always Execute.
}
```